# Google Static Maps API marker z-order

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

Is there any way to force the z-order of markers in Google Static Maps?

There doesn't appear to be any way to specify a z-order and the z-order does not seem to be determined by the order of the markers in the static maps URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently this is not possible.

However, there is a feature request in the public issue tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2096

Please star this feature request to express your interest and receive further updates.

Comment: Starred - seems like the kind of thing that should have been there from the start.